# Git Is Ignoring Most of The Files In the Repo - How to Readd Files Previously Ignored

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I used bedrock a lot:
https://github.com/roots/bedrock

It helps to have all the WordPress stuff in one one repo so I can deploy directly from a git and have everything in one place.

However, when I run:

```
git clone https://github.com/roots/bedrock.git my-project
```

And then add this project to my SourceTree app (GUI for GIT), it is missing the key WordPress folders located in web/wp, which makes sense cause the git ignore: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/roots/bedrock/master/.gitignore has the following:

```
web/wp
web/.htaccess
```

So my question is, how do I re-add these folders to the repo?

I've tried removing them from the gitignore, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Q: How to re-add files previously ignored?  A: Very simple: `git add myfile`.  Or `git add foldername/\\*`.  Or `git add --all`.

Comment: It seems that bedrock is meant to keep these files out, and I install them on the production site running composer install in the root folder. 

However, I'd still love to know how to add previously ignored files into a local git repo. The only workaround I can do is to move all files to a new folder, but this loses   all the previous git comments.

Comment: Bravo paulsm4, this bugged me for ages. So simple. Thank you greatly.